# Facebook Fan since?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I wondered if there is any possibility to figure out since when a fan on Facebook is a fan? The only idea I came up with was to crawl the whole feed of a fan page and track the first like of a wall post. However, this approach is not very accurate.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the Graph API for a User (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) there is the `Likes` connection which returns the `created_time` for each of a user's likes. This is really the only reliable way to determine WHEN a user first liked an object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it only applies to web crawlers but I do know the FB is on the "Do Not Crawl" list (robots.txt) so it may be illegal to do so.  I know you are trying to find an alternate way to do so but just in case nobody else answers I wanted to make it clear that it may be illegal to crawl the page and you probably want to look into that before doing so.

Comment: Actually, I just found this, it appears you can ask FB to be able to crawl http://fb.com/robots.txt Maybe you could ask FB how to find your answer.